# onChange event React typescript what kind of event I need?

Tags: typescript, react-typescript

I have a dilemma, I'm using react typescript and trying to type onChange from select, what kind of event should I put if I get data from event.value NOT event.target.value

Image with select I upload lower

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0):

If you hover your cursor over onChange property it should tell you what type of event is (after the : so `event: <TYPE_HERE>`).

[image: Hover over onchange]

Comment: yes I know, problem is that I first time see event of this type : 

'' Type 'ChangeEventHandler<HTMLSelectElement>' is not assignable to type '(newValue: SingleValue<{ value: string; label: string; }>, actionMeta: ActionMeta<{ value: string; label: string; }>) => void'.''

And if i try to use this type i receive another error, that ActionMeta and SingleValue not found in react-select

Comment: I believe that where you are setting `Statsborgerskap` to e.value could be the issue. I don't think e.value is a string so TypeScript is complaining. Perhaps try `e.target.value`?